# How to execute data from json file via File API?

Tags: javascript, json, html, drag-and-drop, fileapi

I am novice in File API. At the moment I have a task to execute data from json-file using File API and drag-and-drop method. JSON-file example:

```
[
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"VoffCafe",
        "coordinates":{
            "latitude":56.629418,
            "longitude":47.893927
        }
    }
]
```

Data from JSON-file must be written to some variables.

Now I have an example, it is sample on my task, but it shows picture, which is dropped on web-page. Script from this example, which does this, below:

```
<script>
  var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
  state = document.getElementById('status');

  if (typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined') {
  state.className = 'fail';
  } else {
  state.className = 'success';
  state.innerHTML = 'File API & FileReader available';
  }

  holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
  holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
  holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  this.className = '';
  e.preventDefault();

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';
  };
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  return false;
  };
</script>
```

Full page-example, where this script works is here: http://html5demos.com/file-api

How to redo this script to it be satisfied my demands?

Comment: I just added an answer bellow : If you need help understanding more general File API I would be more then willing to give you my email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can brake down the task of a "*local JSON file grabber*" into 3 main steps:

1: **The file selector**

The ondrop event operates as our file selector in this example. [see documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrop.asp).

```
var holder = document.getElementById('holder');

   holder.ondrop = function (e) { 
   var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]; //Gets the most recent dropped file 
   ...do FileReader stuff...
   return false; 
   }
```

---

**2: The Filereader**

Javascript's Filereader often confuses people due to its asynchronous nature. Long story short : 
In the code below the `reader.onload` function is called after `reader.readAsText()` is completed. [see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
var reader = new FileReader();
//.onload event is triggered each time the reading operation is successfully completed.
reader.onload = function (event) {
 ...do Parser stuff... 
}
reader.readAsText(file);//Passes reader the file to read as text (aka String)
```

---

**3. The Parser**

Once you have a string to parse, turning it into an object is dead simple with `JSON.parse()`.
In this example just pass in the file contents with `event.target.result`.

```
reader.onload = function (event) {
    var parsedObj = JSON.parse(event.target.result); 
}
```

---

### putting it all together

```
//JSON file (removed unnecessary brakets)  
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"VoffCafe",
    "coordinates":{
        "latitude":56.629418,
        "longitude":47.893927
    }
}

//HTML file
<script>
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'); 

/*
...Other stuff...
*/

//Step 1 : The File Selector
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    this.className = '';
    e.preventDefault(); // Keeps any default action the element from happening

    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    console.log(file);


    //Step 2 : The File Reader    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {

        //Step : 3 The Parser 
        var parsedObj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);

        //example code : alerts all the methods of parsedObj.
        for(I in parsedObj) {
            if(parsedObj.hasOwnProperty(I)){
                alert(parsedObj[I]);
            }
        }
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
    return false;
};
</script>
```

---

I hope that helps!